# Kernel manjaro does not load, swap unknown

Tags: kernel, crash

I need to recover my system...It broke down after a failed update. I tried to google the solution but I got this:

```
[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# mkdir /mnt

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt’: File exists

[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

loop0    7:0    0    61M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/livefs

loop1    7:1    0 281.3M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs

loop2    7:2    0   1.4G  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs

loop3    7:3    0 432.5M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/rootfs

sda      8:0    1 931.5G  0 disk 

├─sda1   8:1    1  29.8G  0 part 

├─sda2   8:2    1 186.3G  0 part 

├─sda3   8:3    1     1K  0 part 

└─sda5   8:5    1 465.7G  0 part 

sdb      8:16   1   1.8T  0 disk 

sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

sr1     11:1    1   2.2G  0 rom  /run/miso/bootmnt


[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'swap'.

[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# 'swap'

bash: swap: command not found

[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# sudo mount /sda /mnt

mount: /mnt: special device /sda does not exist.

[manjaro-deepin manjaro]# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'swap'.
[manjaro-deepin manjaro]#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried sudo blkid and I got:

Comment: sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="4b89af5d-5dcf-44bd-914d-de5c699c590b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="dcfa759c-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="69417552-09a6-4d3d-954a-b5b27737121b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dcfa759c-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5eaa8c70-3697-43da-8b56-d44d1641d944" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dcfa759c-05"
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="cda46f43" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sr1: UUID="2018-07-12-18-49-30-00" LABEL="MJRO1711" TYPE="iso9660" PTTYPE="dos"

Comment: By the way, I got kernel failed and CUPS failed messages whenever I try to load. Any idea of how to fix my system?